# Telegram Bot: Can we identify if message is from group admin?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have added my bot to a group chat, now for few commands I need to give access only to the group admin, so is it possible to identify if the message sender is admin of the group?
I am using python-telegram-bot library

Comment: This has been answered here.
[Check message sender api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387330/telegram-bot-can-we-identify-if-message-is-from-group-admin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. You can use the [`getChatAdministrators`](http://ptb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.get_chat_administrators) API method (returns a list of [`ChatMember`](http://ptb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.chatmember.html)) to get a list of admins for a chat, or the [`getChatMember`](http://ptb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.get_chat_member) API method (returns a single [`ChatMember`](http://ptb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.chatmember.html)) to get the admin status of a single user.

An efficient method to solve this problem is described here: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#cached-telegram-group-administrator-check

Answer (score 7):

When you use [getUpdates](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getUpdates-d751762a), you can see `.message.chat.type` is `group` or not.

And then use [getChatMember](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getChatMember-b34021bd), `.result.status` should be `administrator` or `creator`.

Answer (score -1):

No. You need to hardcode user id in your source and compare if user id in admin-ids array.